# SSRS 2016 Web protal in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ssrs-2016

We have recently installed SQL 2016 at one of our client.

We encounter error while accessing SSRS 2016 from a machine having IE8.

We know that SSRS 2016 is compatible with MS Edge, IE 10 or 11, Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox

The best option is to upgrade IE on user’s machines and we don’t want to hurt any other application(s) compatibility if it could cause...

So is there any workaround to run SSRS 2016 with IE8?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Support for IE8 reached it's end-of-life on Jan 12th, 2016. Microsoft will no longer be designing web pages to account for older versions of IE.